# Using {% url 'view_name' object %} directly

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

The approach of doing `{% url 'view_name' object.pk object.parent.slug %}` isn't really flexible when switching to completety different url patterns. I'm looking for a way to do `{% url 'view_name' object %}` and to transcribe myself from `object` to `object.pk` and `object.parent.slug` in the url.

Like that

```
- template.html
{% url 'view_name' object %}

- urls.py [not real regex regex]
url('<object__parent__slug>/<object__pk>', views.view_name, name="view_name")
```

I know this is not at all possible with this syntax, but it's just to give an idea of what I'm looking for.

Comment: How often are you planning on switching to completely different url patterns? It should really happen, and a search and replace really isn't that difficult for when it does.

Comment: In reality I'm dealing with deep urls and each time I make simple change, I have to "search and replace" inside my project. Also this is error-prone and it makes a lot of duplication inside my templates.      A more realistic example: https://github.com/MDamien/publicdb/blob/master/publicdb/urls.py#L37-L53  . And the inside the templates: {% url 'new_instance' user.pk api.slug klass.slug %}    But I think found a solution: just adding new url function to my model like "get_edit_url()","get_delete_url()",...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just add url methods inside my models:

```
 class House(model.Models):
      name = models.TextField()
      ....

      def get_edit_url(self):
           return reverse('view_name', {'pk':self.pk, 'name':self.name, 'owner_pk' : self.owner.pk })
```